# PHP Cannot redeclare function after file name changed

Tags: php, mysql, aptana3

I'm getting this error

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getAllStaff() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/StaffTools/database/StaffHandler.php:5) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/StaffTools/database/staffHandler.php on line 15`

I'm building an application in Apatana Studio 3 and I renamed a file from `staffHandler.php` to `StaffHandler.php` **(uppercase S)** so the former no longer exists.

I get all my PHP files from the `database` directory using the below PHP code

```
foreach(glob("database/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```

And then call a method called `getAllStaff()` here:

```
        <select name="staff">
            <?php getAllStaff(); ?>
        </select>
```

Obviously, this method is now in `StaffHandler.php`. This was working fine until I changed the filename of the name.

**Things I've tried**

1. Clearing my cache in Firefox
2. Rebuilding & cleaning my project in Aptana
3. Changing the filename back to `staffHandler.php`
4. Conditional function statemet `if(!function_exists....`

Why on earth would PHP throw an error like that for a file that doesn't exist anymore?

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

I had a reference to the staffHandler.php file buried within all my PHP scripts and I think this was the source of the problem. When I ran `ls -la` at the terminal in the database directory only `StaffHandler.php` appeared but when I ran `find staffHandler.php and rm staffHandler.php` it erased both staff and Staff. Must've been some kind of link between created by application code.

Comment: Are you certain the former file doesnt exist anymore? for example if you renamed the file locally, then uploaded by ftp, the old file will still exist on the server

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Do you have OPcache? Are you sure there is no other such file in the project?

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I'm using OS X.

Comment: @Steve I'm positive. I'm developing on XAMPP locally and the file does not exist.

Comment: Can you paste the first 20 or so lines of `StaffHandler.php`?